# Transpose and sort rows of HTML form submission data without losing associative relationships

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, transpose, submission

I have an HTML form that submits a payload of names and exam scores.

I need to transpose the structure so that exam numbers are grouped together and exam taker names are directly associated with scores.

```
<form action="process.php" method="POST">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th style='width:10%'>No.</th>
            <th style='width:40%'>NAME</th>
            <th  style='text-align: center'>EXAM1</th>
            <th  style='text-align: center'>EXAM2</th>
            <th  style='text-align: center'>EXAM3</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td><input type="text" size="27" name="name[]" required></td>
            <td><input type="text" size="5" name="ex1[]" required></td>
            <td><input type="text"  size="5" name="ex2[]" required></td>
            <td><input type="text"  size="5" name="ex3[]" required></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>2</td>
            <td><input type="text" size="27" name="name[]" required></td>
            <td><input type="text" size="5" name="ex1[]" required></td>
            <td><input type="text"  size="5" name="ex2[]" required></td>
            <td><input type="text"  size="5" name="ex3[]" required></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>3</td>
            <td><input type="text" size="27" name="name[]" required></td>
            <td><input type="text" size="5" name="ex1[]" required></td>
            <td><input type="text"  size="5" name="ex2[]" required></td>
            <td><input type="text"  size="5" name="ex3[]" required></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2"style='text-align: center' ><input type="submit" name="submit" value="SUBMIT REQUEST"></td>
            <td colspan="3" style='text-align: center'> <button type="reset" value="Reset">CLEAR</button></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

My processing/displaying code:

```
<?php        
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $ex1 = $_POST['ex1'];
    $ex2 = $_POST['ex2'];
    $ex3 = $_POST['ex3'];
        
    $exam = array();
        
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($name); $i++) {
        $exam[] = array(
            'name' => $name[$i], 
            'exam1' => $ex1[$i],
            'exam2' => $ex2[$i],
            'exam3' => $ex3[$i],
        );
    }

    echo "<pre>";
        print_r($exam);
    echo "<pre>";

    $keys = array_keys($exam);
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($exam); $i++) {
        echo "<p><b>Exam Result $keys[$i]</b></p>";
        echo "<ul>";
            foreach($exam[$keys[$i]] as $key => $value) {
                echo $key . " : " . $value . "<br>";
            }
        echo "</ul>";
    }
}
```

[image: Original Activity from Prof. Form and Output]

I have no problem assigning the text input to array I having problem displaying the right output.

This is my target output:

Exam Result 1

- Rolly 99
- James 80
- Dave 79

Exam Result 2

- Dave 95
- Rolly 86
- James 80

Exam Result 3

- James 88
- Dave 75
- Rolly 60

Answer (score 0):

```
 echo "<p><b>TOTAL STUDENTS: ". count($exam)."</b></p>";
     for($i = 0; $i < count($exam); $i++) {
        echo "<p><b>Exam Result ".($i +1)."</b></p>";
        $keys = array_column($exam, "exam$i");
        array_multisort($keys, SORT_DESC, $exam);
        foreach ($exam as $row) {
            echo "<li>". $row['name']. " ". $row["exam$i"]."</li>";
        }
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Before combining exam scores with the exam takers' names, be sure to validate the incoming data to avoid code breakage.

The following script is designed to accommodate changes in your HTML form structure (in case the number of exams or exam takers changes).  Despite looping over all elements in the `$_POST` array, the `sscanf()` function plays a dual row of blocking the `name` row from being pushed into the result and it extracts the exam number from the exam keys.

Calling `arsort()` on each built associative row will sort the scores in a descending direction and preserve the names.  The `$i` key in the first level of the result array can be used when displaying the exam number.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/UU4fS))

```
$_POST = [
    'name' => ['Dave', 'James', 'Rolly'],
    'ex1' => [79, 80, 99],
    'ex2' => [95, 80, 86],
    'ex3' => [75, 88, 60]
];

$exams = [];
$totalNames = count($_POST['name'] ?? []);
foreach ($_POST as $key => $row) {
    // because user submissions cannot be trusted...
    if (!sscanf($key, 'ex%d', $i) || $totalNames !== count($row)) {
        continue;
    }
    $exams[$i] = array_combine($_POST['name'], $row);
    arsort($exams[$i]);
}
var_export($exams);
```

Output:

```
array (
  1 => 
  array (
    'Rolly' => 99,
    'James' => 80,
    'Dave' => 79,
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    'Dave' => 95,
    'Rolly' => 86,
    'James' => 80,
  ),
  3 => 
  array (
    'James' => 88,
    'Dave' => 75,
    'Rolly' => 60,
  ),
)
```